# Problem with small brackets in `case` and `array` environment

Tags: arrays, brackets, cases

When I write an equation for cases, the brackets do not adapt to size, they remain very small. Previously I solved a problem with the arrow drawings because I am using Spanish `babel`. I added `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. I don't know if this relates to my problem.

[image: with case environment]

[image: with array environment]

Comment: Welcome to TEx.SWE! What you try so far? such equation is usual set with `cases` math environment.

Comment: @Diego MV when you have a problem you should show us a MWE (Minimal Working Example), which is the minimum necessary code that compiles and shows us the troubles that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

With use of math environment `cases*` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \phi & = \begin{cases*}
            1, & if $u\geq 0$ \\
            0, & otherwise.
          \end{cases*} \\
 f(x) & = \begin{cases*}
            x^2 & : $x=0$ \\
            x^3 & : $y\geq$ 0
          \end{cases*}  
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To write the correct content of equations contents I left to you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that the mathematical arrangements of `cases` and the symbols `<`, `>` came into conflict with `\usepackage{fouriernc}`

Removing the package the problem is solved.

Comment: Without any code such a problem is hard to guess. Maybe adding a minimal not-working example to the original question makes this question more helpful.

Comment: You not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), how should we know anything about your document? Your answer is useless, beside that *it not hold*. If you add `\usepackage{fouriernc}` to code in my answer, you will obtain similar result as I show in it.